# Extend my class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just started to learn OOP in JavaScript and right at the beginning I got some problems.

I want to use jQuery in my own Class like so:

```js
var myclass = function() {
  this.attr1 = false;
  this.target1 = false;
  this.func1 = function() {
    this.target1.text(this.attr1);
    console.log(this.attr1);
  }
}

var testObj = new myclass();
$.extend(testObj, $);
testObj.attr1 = "Hello World";
testObj.target1 = $("#targetcontainer");
testObj.func1();
```

```html
<div id="targetcontainer">some1 out there?</div>
```

But my Container did not change the text. Could you may help me?

Comment: Where exactly did you get this error? Did you include jquery?

Comment: Well i wrote the code wrong... i wrote the class after creating the object. but now the Hello World dont get into my container. I just changed the post

Comment: I made this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2r3n6w6e/ and it's working

Comment: Ok nevermind. I just put everything of testObj in jquery $(document).ready function and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to make sure the dom has been created before you attempt to query for elements using selectors.

```js
var myclass = function() {
  this.attr1 = false;
  this.target1 = false;
  this.func1 = function() {
    this.target1.text(this.attr1);
    console.log(this.attr1);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var testObj = new myclass();
  $.extend(testObj, $);
  testObj.attr1 = "Hello World";
  testObj.target1 = $("#targetcontainer");
  testObj.func1();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="targetcontainer">some1 out there?</div>
```